# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 for extension with an Alamofire.Request

Tags: swift2, linker-errors, alamofire

I created a protocol for `Alamofire.Response`, and then extend it like this

```
import Alamofire
public protocol MyResponseType {
    typealias Value
    typealias Error: ErrorType
    var request: NSURLRequest? { get }
    var response: NSHTTPURLResponse? { get }
    var data: NSData? { get }
    var result: Alamofire.Result<Value, Error> { get }
    init(request: NSURLRequest?, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, data: NSData?, result: Alamofire.Result<Value, Error>, timeline: Alamofire.Timeline)
}

extension Alamofire.Response: MyResponseType {}
```

The building process passed, but when it comes to link, it fails. Here comes the errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Alamofire.Response.data.getter : __ObjC.NSData?", referenced from:
      protocol witness for wtftest. MyResponseType.data.getter : __ObjC.NSData? in conformance <A, B where B: Swift.ErrorType> Alamofire.Response<A, B> : wtftest. MyResponseType in wtftest in ViewController.o
  "Alamofire.Response.result.getter : Alamofire.Result<A, B>", referenced from:
      protocol witness for wtftest. MyResponseType.result.getter : Alamofire.Result<A.Value, A.Error> in conformance <A, B where B: Swift.ErrorType> Alamofire.Response<A, B> : wtftest.ProducerResponseType in wtftest in ViewController.o
  "Alamofire.Response.request.getter : __ObjC.NSURLRequest?", referenced from:
      protocol witness for wtftest. MyResponseType.request.getter : __ObjC.NSURLRequest? in conformance <A, B where B: Swift.ErrorType> Alamofire.Response<A, B> : wtftest. MyResponseType in wtftest in ViewController.o
  "Alamofire.Response.response.getter : __ObjC.NSHTTPURLResponse?", referenced from:
      protocol witness for wtftest. MyResponseType.response.getter : __ObjC.NSHTTPURLResponse? in conformance <A, B where B: Swift.ErrorType> Alamofire.Response<A, B> : wtftest.ProducerResponseType in wtftest in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is this a bug of swift? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Please mention `ProducerResponseType` too

Comment: @SohilR.Memon sorry, `ProducerResponseType` is actually MyResponseType here, forgot to modify it,

Comment: I'm banging my head against the wall regarding this also. Only fails when targeting the simulator, but device still works fine.